# Proof that $A^2 = A$ where A and B are square matrices , if $BA = B$ and $AB = A$. What did I do wrong?

Tags: matrices, proof-verification

**The problem**

Given that for square matrices $A$ and $B$ of the same order,
$AB = A$
$BA = B$
Prove that $A^{2} = A$.

**My proof**

$$
\text{Starting with the given condition ,}\\
BA = B\\
\text{Premultiplying } B^{-1} \text{ to both sides , we get ,}\\
(B^{-1} \cdot B )\cdot A = (B^{-1} \cdot B )\\
\text{so , }\ \ \ I \cdot A = I\\
\text{or , }\ \ \ A = I\\
\text{Therefore }\ \ \ A^2 = I^2 = I = A
$$

According to my teacher , this is wrong and not *how* it should have been proved.
I couldn't yet see what I did wrong , could some one please tell me where I made a mistake .

Comment: Quite simply you can see that $A=B=0$ (the zero matrix) the conditions hold, but $A\neq I$. You can't "divide by $B$" unless it is non-singular (equivalent to not dividing by zero). You can also note that if $Av=0$ then also $Bv=BAv=0$ so that $B$ and $A$ have the same null space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't know if B is invertible so you cannot multiply by $B^{-1}$!
You can instead try multiplying by A on both sides. 
$A(BA)=AB \Rightarrow (AB)A = A \Rightarrow A.A=A \Rightarrow A^2 = A$

Comment: Thanks , you pointed my mistake as well as showed how to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

$A^2 = A \cdot A = (AB)A = A (BA) = AB = A$

Comment: This is a good proof, but the OP has asked for someone to verify their proof-- not supply their own.